# What are Aliases and Difference between tf.compat.v1 and tf.compat.v2?

Tags: tensorflow, upgrade, tensorflow2.0

I have the following questions:

1. What are Aliases in TF2 Documents such as for [tf.keras.utils.get_file](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant)? Does this mean we can use both tf.foo and tf.compat.v1.foo?
2. What are Difference between tf.compat.v1 and tf.compat.v2?

Answer (score 3):

`tf.compat` is the compatibility module. **v1** is the version 1.x of TensorFlow, while **v2** is the version 2.x of TensorFlow (so although strange, you have tf2 inside tf2, through `tf.compat.v2`).

For the aliases: yes, if a function is an alias of another, you can use the one you prefer. However, using the compatibility module is often not needed and I recommend to do not reply on it too much (usually it is better to find the tf2 equivalent way of doing something, instead of writing code in the tf1 style, through `tf.compat.v1`)

Comment: So, what is tf.compat.v2 then?

Comment: Tensorflow v2, inside tensorflow v2

Comment: Doesn't this mean if a code has alias with tf.compat.v2, we can safely use tf.foo instaead of tf.compat.v2.foo?

Comment: Yes, when you're using tensorflow 2.0 -> tf.* = tf.compat.v2.*

Comment: Maybe it means the function is not a new addition to Tensorflow or maybe a flag or maker for google developer for later upgrades. I am pretty sure TF 3 will not wait too long!

Comment: Hopefully without the same amount of changes introduced between tf1 and tf2 :) btw if my answer solved your problem (or in this case, clarified your doubt) please remember to mark it as accepted!

Comment: so basically, tf.compat.v1 is used to go back to version 1, and tf.compat.v1 is used to switch to version 2. So in the same file, we can use functions from both versions, right?
Although I would usually prefer using version 2 [the latest versions are mostly better than previous versions].

Comment: exactly @DrNishaArora